# Create and rename dataframes dynamically

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to run a list of dataframes through the renaming (and code) of df1 and df2. Can this be done by def ....etc., or any other method?

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {
   'A': ['d','d','d','d','d','d','g','g','g','g','g','g','k','k','k','k','k','k'],
   'B': [5,5,6,4,5,6,-6,7,7,6,-7,7,-8,7,-6,6,-7,50],
   'C': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
   'S': [2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2012,2012,2014,2015,2016,2012,2013,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2014]     
    } );

df = (df.B + df.C).groupby([df.A, df.S]).agg(['sum','size']).unstack(fill_value=0)
df1 = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
new_cols= list(zip(df1.columns.get_level_values(0),['total'] * len(df.columns)))
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_cols)
df2 = pd.concat([df1,df], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df2.columns = ['_'.join((col[0], str(col[1]))) for col in df2.columns]
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('sum_','')
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('size_','T')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use custom function:

```
def func(df):
    df = (df.B + df.C).groupby([df.A, df.S]).agg(['sum','size']).unstack(fill_value=0)
    df1 = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
    new_cols= list(zip(df1.columns.get_level_values(0),['total'] * len(df.columns)))
    df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_cols)
    df2 = pd.concat([df1,df], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
    df2.columns = ['_'.join((col[0], str(col[1]))) for col in df2.columns]
    df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('sum_','')
    df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('size_','T')
    return df2

print (func(df))    
   T2012  2012  T2013  2013  T2014  2014  T2015  2015  T2016  2016  Ttotal  \
A                                                                            
d      2    13      1     6      1     7      1     5      1     6       6   
g      2   -11      1     8      1     8      1     8      1     7       6   
k      1    -6      1     9      2    48      1     8      1    -5       6   

   total  
A         
d     37  
g     20  
k     54
```

If need procees multiple dataframes:

```
for df in [df1,df2,df3]:
    print (func(df))
```

If need output to list of dataframes:

```
dfs = [func(df) for df in [df1,df2,df3]]
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, thanks. One question, would the name of the df's I put through stay the same as they were?

Comment: If use list of `DataFrames`, you can select dataframes by positions like `dfs[0]` is first dataframe, `df[1]` is second... List of dataframes is very good if need concat all dataframes together, then use only ``df=pd.concat(dfs)`

Comment: Ok, thanks. But if I wouldn't, does the name remains the same?

Comment: I think it depends of assign - all dataframes will be `df5` if use `for df in [df1,df2,df3]:
    df5 =func(df) ` - in each iteration can be overwritten and last get `df5` from last `df3`. so need store them - e.g. to list then use `dfs = []`
`for df in [df1,df2,df3]:`
    `dfs.append(func(df))`.

Comment: If I run dfs now I get the wanted output, however, can I get the individual dataframes as well, maybe even rename them?

Comment: Ok, so we have to use this comments. So if have source `df1`, `df2` and `df3` what is desired names of output dataframes? this names are in some list like `names=['dfa','dfb','dfc']` and need add `df1` to `dfa`, `df2` to `dfb`, ...?

Comment: I've posted a new question